# How to find current roles available on a database

Tags: oracle

I am looking to provide grant to one of my function in my database.
However, I am not sure what roles I should give access to.

I searched for it but can't find list of roles for all the users.

Any idea guys as which table I should be looking into.

I am using Oracle 11g.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: your supposed to know what roles you run a function, by definition.

Comment: and how I am supposed to know that... Actually I want to provide grant to another user of the same database... but not sure what roles I should grant access on.

Comment: Be aware that role grants do not work as you think they do when packages and stored procedures are concerned. See Tom explaining http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1065832643319

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find this information in the DBA_* views in Oracle.

To find all roles in the database:

```
select * from dba_roles
```

To find what roles a particular user has:

```
select * from dba_role_privs where grantee=<user name>
```